# What happens to ECS containers that exceed soft memory limit when there is memory contention?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

Say I have an instance with 2G memory, and a task/container with 0.5G soft memory limit, and 0.75G hard memory limit.

The instance is running 3 containers, each consuming 0.6G memory. Now a 4th container needs to be added? What happens to the 3 running containers? Is their memory allocation reduced? Or are they migrated to another instance? What if there is no other instance, will the 4th container be placed?

I understand how soft and hard CPU limits work since CPU is a dynamic resource (the application can handle spikes in free CPU). In case of memory, however, you cannot really take away memory from a container that is already using it.

Answer (score 1):

The 4th container will not be able to spawn and you will get the below error.

```
(service sample) was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching (container-instance 05016874-f518-4b7a-a817-eb32a4d387f1) has insufficient memory available. For more information, see the Troubleshooting section of the Amazon ECS Developer Guide.
```

You need to add another ecs instance if you want to schedule the 4th container. all other 3 containers will be in the steady state. Nothing like memory allocation reduced happened in the cluster. If there is no instance your service will always be in an unsteady state and continue to give you the above errors.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually, memory can be reclaimed from running processes. For example the kernel may evict memory that is backed by files (like the code of the process itself). If the data ends up being needed again the kernel can page it back in. This is explained a little in this blog post: https://chrisdown.name/2018/01/02/in-defence-of-swap.html

If the task is scheduled on that node but the kernel fails to reclaim enough memory to avoid an out-of-memory situation then one of the processes will get killed by the kernel, which docker will detect and kill the container, which ECS will notice. I'm not sure if ECS will try to reschedule the dead task on the same instance or a different one. It probably depends.